# How to pick up values from config files other than application.properties in Java Spring project

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I am building a Kafka project in Spring and I needed to store sensitive information like access tokens within my project. So, I created a secrets.properties file inside my resources folder, added my confidential information in that file, and added the following line to my application.properties file:

```
spring.config.import=optional:secrets.properties
```

I now want to access the information stored inside the newly created secrets file inside my Java class, but am unsure how to do that. Can someone guide me on how to do this?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can use ClassPathResource. Assuming secrets.properties is in the src/main/resources folder `ClassPathResource("secrets.properties")`.

Comment: Thanks, that path is the correct one. How do I go about accessing the values from the file after this?

Comment: Take a look at https://www.baeldung.com/properties-with-spring. Good example of what you are asking for.